# How do I add a logo on the navigation bar?

Tags: uinavigationcontroller, xcode5, graphical-logo

[image: Pic from Highlight app]

like this one on "highlight" app. theres a nice logo "highlight" on the center of navigation controller. can someone help? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this tutorial very helpful in dealing with my custom NavBars. Hope it helps!
http://www.appcoda.com/customize-navigation-status-bar-ios-7/

Comment: Glad I could help! Best to you and your header!

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [this](http://www.appcoda.com/customize-navigation-status-bar-ios-7/)

scroll down to "adding image to navigation bar tittle, you'll find all you need there.